# HTML <option> tag tooltip

Tags: html, events, html-select

I have a `<select>` tag with many `<option>` child nodes. I want to keep the width of this drop-down list to a minimum size. However, there are times when the innerHTML of at least one option is very long, forcing the drop-down list box to expand its width.

What I'm planning to do is to truncate the long text and use ellipses to denote that some characters have been truncated ("very loooooong sentence" becomes "very loooooo..."). To show the full text, I'm thinking of using tooltip message on mouse over event.

Unfortunately, the onmouseover event for each  tag doesn't seem to work. What can I do to achieve this effect?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS on the <option> tag? There's a max-width (or width for IE) attribute, so by setting this will keep the option box to a maximum width. As for tooltip, I know you can do it using JQuery.

Comment: The max-width/width css attribute worked. however, I'm trying to show the full text by just using the default features of HTML

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding a title attribute to each option should do the trick.

```
<option value="1" title="Long description">Short desc...</option>
```

Comment: AFAIK, yes. Title is a standard HTML attribute and should work across browsers and operating systems. It probably won't work in touch devices such as the iPhone, though (because there is no cursor to move over the options).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the `<select>` and the dropdown will extend beyond the width of the select. Try the following:

```
<select style="width: 30px">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>really long</option>
  <option>even more longer</option>
  <option>This should be long enough to stretch to the end of the page, but the select is still not very long</option>
</select>
```