# Display the tool-tip for drop-down option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Here is my select drop-down box `.hbs` code, I need to add the tool-tip for `content.name` (drop-down labels) on mouseover.

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding=entities
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  prompt="-- Select --"
  valueBinding=entityId }}
```

`content.name` it will retreive the name from array object

Comment: I think you need to add mouseEnter/mouseLeave but I'm not sure if you can do it in the handlebars template directly. You may have to create a View which extends Ember.Select.

Comment: You will need to extend both the ember Select and the ember SelectOption if you want to reuse their code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML <option> tag tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205733/html-option-tag-tooltip)